# How to access nested object array values for ag-grid table data and details?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have JSON data that looks similar to this:

```js
[{
    "id": "id1234",
    "thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId": [{
        "id": "id1234",
        "property": "propertyValue",
        "previousValue": "123",
        "updatedValue": "456"
      },
      {
        "id": "id1234",
        "property": "propertyValue2",
        "previousValue": "000",
        "updatedValue": "001"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id456",
    "thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId": [{
        "id": "id456",
        "property": "name",
        "previousValue": "Anakin Skywalker",
        "updatedValue": "Darth Vader"
      },
      {
        "id": "id456",
        "property": "lightsaberColor",
        "previousValue": "blue",
        "updatedValue": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I am able to make a table using ag-grid that displays the ID and the length of the things that have changed array. I achieve this by mapping through the JSON response and returning the values like this:

```
.then(JSON => JSON.map(thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId=> (
    {
      id: `${thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId.personNumber}`,
      thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId: `${thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId.thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId.length}`
    }))
  )
  .then(thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId=> {
    return thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId;
  })
```

This allows me to display the data I need in two different rows by setting the table data to this JSON response:

```
 someApi.getthingsThatHaveChangedForThisId().then(tableData => this.setState({
  tableData: tableData,
  }))
```

I would like to now make the details of the thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId array display as a drop down/accordion type menu when clicking on the row. I need to display the values associated with the thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId array for each ID. So each id would have details like:

```
{
            "id": "id1234",
            "property": "propertyValue",
            "previousValue": "123",
            "updatedValue": "456"
        },
```

I have tried mapping Object.keys and Object.values over the thingsThatHaveChangedForThisId array but it always returns undefined. I am thinking I need to use some kind of nested mapping but I am unable to find any answers that satisfy my conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!